# How to use axios to upload image from imagePicker

Tags: react-native, axios

I trying to upload a file image to API in postman thats work fine but when a i try file image from ImagePicker didnot work.

I think doing something wrong when create formdata

Handler

```
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(optionsImagePicker, (response) => {
  console.log('Response = ', response);

  if (response.didCancel) {
    console.log('User cancelled image picker');
  } else if (response.error) {
    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
  } else if (response.customButton) {
    console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
  } else {
    // const source = { image: response.data };
    let photo = { uri: response.uri}
    let formdata = new FormData();
    
    formdata.append("product[name]", 'test')
    formdata.append("product[price]", 10)
    formdata.append("product[category_ids][]", 2)
    formdata.append("product[description]", '12dsadadsa')
    formdata.append("product[images_attributes[0][file]]", {uri: photo.uri, name: 'image.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg'})
    

    updateProfilePic(formdata)

    // You can also display the image using data:
    // const source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };

    // this.setState({
    //   avatarSource: source,
    // });
  }
});
```

Service

```
export function uploadImageProfile(data: any): Promise<any> {

  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  };
  return api.post('/users/profilepic', {image: data}, config).then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data);
    return res.data;
  });
}
```

Comment: which react native version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed how I send image to the server. Now send im base64 and in server convert to file with `fs`.

```
    const uploadImage = {
      imageBase64: 'data:' + response.type + ';base64,' + response.data,
    };

    updateProfilePic(uploadImage);
```

server side

```
  async saveImageProfile(imageBase64, logedUserData) {
    let base64Image = imageBase64.imageBase64.split(';base64,').pop();
    let type = imageBase64.imageBase64.split('image/').pop().split(';')[0];
    let newFileName = `${logedUserData.id}.${type}`;
    if (imageFileFilter(type)) {
      const file = await fs.writeFile('./files/' + newFileName, base64Image, { encoding: 'base64' }, function (err) {
        console.log('File created');
      });
      const url = `${baseUrl}/users/files/${newFileName}`;
      this.updateRefProfilePic(url, logedUserData);
    }
    else {
      throw new BadRequestException("Tipo de arquivo não suportado");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form data must be like that.

```
formdata.append('file',{
    uri: Platform.OS === 'android' ? photo.uri : 'file://' + photo.uri,
    name: 'test',
    type: 'image/jpeg' // or your mime type what you want
});
```

Then

```
axios.post('/users/profilepic', formdata, config).then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data);
    return res.data;
  });
```

Comment: in sever side show this error: Error: Multipart: Boundary not found

Comment: which library do you use while connecting API?

Comment: If you don't use axios, please try with axios. you write 'axios.post' instead of 'api.post'

Comment: api post is a class of axios default url and default headers: axios.create() is api

Comment: I edit my answer with some changes, can you try it?

Comment: axios calculate boundary automatically.

Comment: dont work and my api service is: 
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    const api = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api'
    })
    
    export default api;

Answer (score 0):

```
let formdata = new FormData();

formdata.append('file',{
  uri: Platform.OS === 'android' ? photo.uri : 'file://' + photo.uri,
  name: 'test',
  type: 'image/jpeg'
});
```

use **method:"POST"** and spread `formdata.getHeaders()` into header

```
let reqObj = {
  method: "POST",
  url: 'http://example.com/upload/image',
  headers: { 
    'x-sh-auth': token,
    ...formdata.getHeaders()
  },
  maxContentLength: Infinity,
  maxBodyLength: Infinity
};


  axios(reqObj).then(result => {
    console.log(result)
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  });
```